# Variable scoping in newcommand

Tags: macros

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\something{something}
\something

    {
        \def\something{another thing}

      \something
    }

    \something
\end{document}
```

From the output it can be seen that there are two variables `something` each living in their own scope:

[image]

Now, I put a variable to live inside a `newcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\something{something}
\newcommand{\dosomething}{
  invoking ``dosomething''
  \def\something{another thing}

  \something
}
\begin{document}
\something

\dosomething

\something
\end{document}
```

From output it can be seen that invoking the `newcommand` altered the previous definition of the variable:

[image]

This can lead to obscure errors particularly with libraries involving hundreds of variables. Is there a way to protect my variables from being altered by `newcommand`s? What is the best approach?

Comment: Well, in the second example you have no group. `\newcommand` does not create a group by itself. You could do `\newcommand{\dosomething}{{...}}`.

Comment: a macro is just expanded inline essentially as a textual replacement, it implies no grouping itself. You can of course define the replacement text of the command to include a group,  But mixing `\def` and `\newcommand` in the same code is likely to lead to obscure errors clearer to stick to primitive constructs or latex ones, not a mixture of the two.

Comment: @campa better to use the more explicit `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, imho.

Comment: Your macros can have names from which you can see what they (are intended to) do. E.g., instead of `\dosomething` you could name the thing `\WithinTheCurrentScopeTurnSomethingIntoAnotherThing`.  At first glimpse long macro names which have a semantical aspect as they explain what the thing does seem cumbersome. But they can be very nice when the need of debugging arises.

Comment: By default (re)definitions in terms of `\newcommand`/`\renewcommand`  apply to the **current** scope. In order to prevent this make sure that another local scope is opened up **before** the (re)definition-assignments in question are carried out. E.g., by means of `\begingroup..\endgroup` or `{..}` or `\bgroup..\egroup`.  In case you wish (re)definitions in terms of `\(re)newcommand` to apply to all superordinate scopes also, look at the package letltxmacro, especially the command `\GlobalLetLtxMacro`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX offers a macro expansion mechanism; the macro is replaced by the replacement text. Therefore, with your current definition

```
\newcommand{\dosomething}{
  invoking ``dosomething''
  \def\something{another thing}

  \something
}
```

the document

```
\begin{document}
\something

\dosomething

\something
\end{document}
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
\begin{document}
\something

invoking ``dosomething''
\def\something{another thing}

\something

\something
\end{document}
```

(plus a couple of trailing spaces you have been somewhat careless about `:-)`)

If you want changes to `\something` to be restricted to the execution of `\dosomething` you must include a level of grouping, either with explicit braces `{...}` or (more readable) with the primitives `\begingroup`/`\endgroup`

```
\newcommand{\dosomething}{% <-- don't forget this
  \begingroup
  invoking ``dosomething''%
  \def\something{another thing}%

  \something
  \endgroup
}
```